# C++ Builder 10.2 how to support Windows 10 App Mode

Tags: c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 10.2 to create some small apps that will be ran on Windows 10.

I would like to support the Windows 10 Theme "app mode" Light and Dark.  (You can see this by RMB on desktop > Personalize..., Settings dialog > Themes > Color, 'Choose your default app mode')

I don't think I'm referring to the VCL styles?  I can't seem to make these work automagically when the user toggles their windows theme from Light to Dark or vice versus.

I've tried setting the background color of the main TForm to color 'clWindow' but this doesn't seem to respect the theme app mode when I toggle it from Light to Dark and vice versus.

What do I need to to do to support the Windows 10 app mode?

Comment: @KenWhite, I've seen the styles, but I don't see how to make the app switch automagically whenever the user toggles their windows theme from Light to Dark or vice versus

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You may want to edit to make it a little more clear what you're asking (as you did in your comment).

Comment: @KenWhite, no worries, I've updated the question with more information.  Thanks!